# HTML tag not covering full content

Tags: html

I want that my `html` tag covers all the content when it overflows the webpage but if I set `html` tag to 100% it only covers the 100% of the height and width of my screen.

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/).

How can I make that the `html` tag cover always the content?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage heights are calculated from the height of their parents.

Since the html has no parent height, it get's the viewport height, which is not what you want.

What you actually want to do is *omit* a height declaration on the `html` tag, and then your `.container` height will expand to contain all of its content (since the parent no longer has a height, it can expand as much as it wants).

So simply

```
html, body{
   width: 100%; // no height declaration
}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is how it works.
If u let height empty or auto, it will adapt to the content.

Comment: What is auto height of root element you think?

Comment: Thank you! It works! But can you explain a bit more why if I set height: 100% it does not adapt the full content?

Comment: Height: 100% takes full height of a parent element. However, html and body have only screen as a "parent", so it takes height of screen.

Comment: @Mamut 
Not "screen" but "window" or "frame".   Check this: `html { height:auto; outline:3px red solid; outline-offset:-3px; }` to see what height:auto means for root element.

Comment: @c-smile Well, thanks for correcting me. However, I still dont get your point. Height auto is also default value, by itself it has no height, but it will wrap the elements inside.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height:max-content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I have a doubt: what is the difference between `max-content` and let the height adapt automatically as @Mamut  points out?

Comment: One additional question. I need that the divs that overflows will be dynamic so it also can be only 3. If I let height adapt to the content if there is only 3 it does not wraps the full webpage (the entirely viewport). How can I make that if there is less content of the full viewport the webpage will be adapt to the entirely viewport and if there is more content than overflows it will also wraps it?